# Jquery Bootstrap drop down call server side method

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-modal, dropdown

Issue:
I am using jquery bootstrap dr0pdown for multiselect using a asp list box which actually turns into  multiselect dropdown . the issue is i can't  call the server side method automatically after i select the items and close the drop down.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This link might help solving it. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-server-side-methods-using-JavaScript-and-JQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx. This second link is probably more like your issue. http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/03/jquery-multiselect-dropdown-list-with-checkboxes.html.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the events that came along with the jquery multiselect and that fixed the issue.